# How to avoid content in the inside div appearing first on hover?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have created a expanding div on hover. Here is the Fiddle i created

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.8s;
}

.innerone {
  height: 100px;
}

.outer:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="outer">
  <div class+="innerone">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class+="inner">



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/ab4Lfdhu/35/
```

But the problem is content inside the expanding div appear first even before div completing its full expanding transition . How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transitions, you can use the following snippet of jQuery to detect that the animation has finished:

```
$(".outer").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
    overflow: visible;
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/db3p5nrv/

Comment: Thank you Jason :)

Comment: It is good pratice to write less code, so it would be more wise to accept my answer instead of writing more code.

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 160px;
}
```

remove `overflow: visible;`
and it should work fine.